# Looking for a Jinja online (or at least live) parser

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm having a hard time understanding how some of the Jinja directives are working.  In order to run a few tests (and, eventually, share the results, jsfiddle style), I'd really appreciate to have some online parser, but couldn't find anything on the Web.

Does it even exist ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I ended up with building one myself. It's available on [Github](https://github.com/qn7o/jinja2-live-parser), and here is how it looks like:
[image: jinja live parser preview]

Comment: 0
down vote
I get the same error as what Ansible throws so this is working. Missing end of comment tag

Is a wordpress config file and the salts are included in this case so there are hashes all over that are throwing the parser off. I think I know what to do. Thanks for this tool, it'll save me time debugging later. One thing to mention is the fact that once the tool errors it YOU MUST reload it in order to verify the fix, you may want to look into that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bubakazouba Fine from here.

Comment: The online version's link is broken :(

Comment: yep broken link

Answer (score 9):

I've put a slightly modified implementation of the original solution to http://jinja.quantprogramming.com/.

Results update dynamically as the user types.

Following [grizzthedj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7128479/grizzthedj)'s suggestion to include the essentials of the answer, install the `jinja` package in python with

```
$ pip install jinja2
```

and as an example run in python

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> print(Template('Dear {{ name }}').render({'name': 'Jane'}))
```

Here, `Dear {{ name }}` is a template and `{'name': 'Jane'}` is a dict of key-value pairs to be used in the template. Running the two lines above displays

```
Dear Jane
```

Answer (score 3):

The OP posted a really cool solution, based on this I have created a lighter version which uses [bottle.py](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/). The user interface is exactly the same, but the Python code is a bit more minimalist, and can be easily integrated into existing applications.

You can find the full code in the following repository [bottle-jinja-live](https://github.com/oz123/bottle-jinja-live)

Answer (score 2):

Since the links in the previous answers don't work anymore, here's a list of online tools I found:

- https://cryptic-cliffs-32040.herokuapp.com/
- https://j2live.ttl255.com/
- https://jinja101.infrastructureascode.ch/
- https://td4a.codethenetwork.com/
- https://textfsm.nornir.tech/

There is also a CLI tool for rendering and validating jinja templates. [NetTowel - Jinja](https://github.com/InfrastructureAsCode-ch/nettowel#jinja2)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32880060)